# How to correctly connect mysqli with PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

How can I improve this code? It opens a new connection every single time? It's old cms and still got mysql. I need to rewrite that to mysqli.

It already works, but I think it isn't good practice.

It is a few more files like login.php and every single one will connect the same way.

connection.php:

```
class connection {

  protected $link;
  private $_host = "host";
  private $_username = user
  private $_password = "pass";
  private $_database = "dbname";

function __construct() {
    $this->connect();
    
}
public function connect(){
    $this->link = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_username, $this->_password, $this->_database);
    return $this->link;
  }
// other methods

}
```

login.php:

```
include ("connection.php");

class login
{
  protected $login;
  protected $pass;
  protected $dbcon;

  function __construct()
  {
    $dbconnection =  new connection();
    $this->dbcon = $dbconnection->connect();    
  }
// other methods

}
```

subpage.php

```
include ("connection.php");
class subpage 
{
  protected $dbcon;

  function __construct()
  {
    $dbconnection = new connection(); 
    $this->dbcon = $dbconnection->connect();
  }
// other methods
}
```

subpage_edit.php:

```
require_once ("connection_class.php");
class subpage_edit extends subpage
{

  protected $dbcon;

  function __construct()
  {
  $dbconnection = new connection(); 
    $this->dbcon = $dbconnection->connect();
}
// other methods
}
```

Comment: Why not connect just **once**? You could implement this through a DI container, or through a static factory for the connection

Comment: Take a look at the manual first. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php You don't need to open a connection each time. Open it once at the start of your application and then pass it as an argument

Comment: @Nico Haase i can do it with static function, but i thought it was bad habit. 
I wilk read something about di containers, any advices?

Comment: A di container only helps if your code is thoroughly object-oriented and you don't create objects manually but they all created by your code. other wise a di container can be easily misused and become huge global variable.